# Does Lastpass only remeber details for websites, not other programs etc.?

Tags: password-management, lastpass

Can Lastpass remember things that aren't on websites? For example does it have a section where you can enter passwords to log into other operating systems?

Comment: haven't used lastpass but keypass lets you enter user/pass for whatever. keypass lets you create a group. can't you do that in lastpass. i see an option to https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/password-manager-basics/adding-a-site/grouping-sites/  so maybe you can do it for things that aren't websites.

Comment: @barlop I have been using Keepass and was going to switch to Lastpass. The situation between Lastpass and Keepass is very sticky because both do many things the other does, but both do many things the other does not do. This is very bad because installing one instead of the other there would be features missing (e.g. Lastpass can only save website passwords but Keepass can't integrate into the browser and store passwords easily). I think I'm going to use both but this seems kind of wasteful in terms of space and startup time.

Comment: Another decision one has to make between Lastpass and Keepass is if they want all their passwords stored on remote servers. Pros: 1)accessible anywhere with internet 2)don't have to worry about backups Cons: 1)less secure 2)requires interent

Comment: haven't used lastpass but keypass stores them locally. you could put it in a directory backed up with dropbox. online backup but thought to be quite secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [LastPass for Applications](https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/upgrading-to-premium/lastpass-for-applications/) that works for applications. Depending on what you run to get into an OS, it might work.

Answer (score 2):

You can create *Secure Notes* with LastPass. These are free-form text, and can contain anything at all. You could use this for other passwords, combinations to safes, telephone codes, etc. Secure Notes are stored encrypted like everything else in LastPass.